# Create person or group column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, custom-form, custom-field-types

I am Creating a "Upcoming Training List" (custom list):

I need to create a system where Managers can log in and enroll their team members in a certain upcoming training.

What I did:

I added a column to the list of type person or group.
I created a new EditForm for the list containing only this field.

What I need is a way for Managers to login and fill this field without being able to see what other managers entered.

Is there a way to implement a text box and when you enter a name in this text box it automatically fills the field? if not what choices do I have?

Please note that I am using SharePoint Designer 2013 and not using VS

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way will be to create a view which shows only those items in which **Created By= [Me] or Team Member =[Me]** filter. This view will shows only those items which are created by current logged in user or if the training is assigned to that user. So other managers will not see other training which they have not created. Make this view as the default view.

But if you want a full proof system , then you must be implementing item level permission.You can create a workflow , which will break inheritance and give permission only to the manager and his team member. See this [blog](http://spcycle.blogspot.co.at/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html).

**Edit**: You will have to use a Training List , which will have only training. Create another list called "Attendees List". This list will have a person or group column and a look up column to training list. Each manager will create a new item when they want to assign any training to team members.Apply the abovew view logic to the attendees list.

Comment: thanks for your reply, the thing is that each training is an item of a custom list, and each training/item of this list has a column named "attendees" of type "Person Or Group" lookup with multiple select,  each manager will access the same item/training and edit this field. and this field shows other managers' changes to it including the actual data, so managers can delete other managers' data. what i need to do is hide managers field data input from other managers. it manager can see the data he entered in this field.

Comment: You mean to say you want all the managers to edit same field and append data to that field without seeing/editing other managers data entered in that very same field?

Comment: yes if it is possible

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible.See my edited answer and follow that approach